# How to filter and retrieve nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I have the following JSON data structure. I am looking to create a function which can return the X Y Z values associated with a specific "ID". I am working in NodeJs and have been working with parsedData = JSON.parse(JSONdata). Havent worked with parsing JSON data much so I'm confused what is the proper way to solve an issue like this.

```
"RTLSTranspondersOption4": 
        [{
            "ID": "a",
            "X": "1",
            "Y": "2",
            "Z": "3",
        }, {
            "ID": "b",
            "X": "4",
            "Y": "5",
            "Z": "6"
        }, {
            "ID": "c",
            "X": "7",
            "Y": "8",
            "Z": "9"
        }]
```

I am looking to create a function like the following:

```
let configJSON2 = fs.readFileSync('TestConfig.JSON').toString()
let parsedData = JSON.parse(configJSON2)

getData(ID, desiredAxis){
 return parsedData.filter...????
}
```

Example: getData(b, X) returns 4.

I am creating the structure of this JSON data so I can reorganize it to fit whatever structure makes most sense so feel free to give suggestions on more efficient ways to structure the data.

Any additional resources related to this subject is also welcome.

Entire JSON as requested:

```
{
    "MindSphereRSA": {
        "content": {
          "baseUrl": "https://southgate.eu1.mindsphere.io",
          "iat": "X",
          "clientCredentialProfile": [
            "RSA_3072"
          ],
          "clientId": "X",
          "tenant": "X"
        },
        "expiration": "X"
      },
      "MindSpherePrivateKey": "X",
      "RTLSDatabaseConnectionString": {
        "user": "X",
        "password": "X",
        "server": "X",
        "database": "X",
        "encrypt": false 
    },
      "RTLSTranspondersOption4": 
        [{
            "ID": "a",
            "X": "1",
            "Y": "2",
            "Z": "3",
        }, {
            "ID": "b",
            "X": "4",
            "Y": "5",
            "Z": "6"
        }, {
            "ID": "c",
            "X": "7",
            "Y": "8",
            "Z": "9"
        }]

      
}
```

Comment: post your entire JSON

Comment: Edited to include entire JSON.

Comment: What does `parsedData` contain

Comment: parsed data contains result of readFileSync('JSONdata.JSON').tostring()

Comment: let configJSON2 = fs.readFileSync('TestConfig.JSON').toString()
let parsedData = JSON.parse(configJSON2)

Comment: So parsedData is the JSON which you updated in the question ?

Comment: Yes it is. So I can access RTLSTranspondersOption4 by going parsedData.RTLSTranspondersOption4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to filter for specific object based on the `ID` and `desiredAxis` specified.

```js
const parsedData = {
    "MindSphereRSA": {
        "content": {
          "baseUrl": "https://southgate.eu1.mindsphere.io",
          "iat": "X",
          "clientCredentialProfile": [
            "RSA_3072"
          ],
          "clientId": "X",
          "tenant": "X"
        },
        "expiration": "X"
      },
      "MindSpherePrivateKey": "X",
      "RTLSDatabaseConnectionString": {
        "user": "X",
        "password": "X",
        "server": "X",
        "database": "X",
        "encrypt": false 
    },
      "RTLSTranspondersOption4": 
        [{
            "ID": "a",
            "X": "1",
            "Y": "2",
            "Z": "3",
        }, {
            "ID": "b",
            "X": "4",
            "Y": "5",
            "Z": "6"
        }, {
            "ID": "c",
            "X": "7",
            "Y": "8",
            "Z": "9"
        }]
};

const getData = function(options, ID, desiredAxis) {
    const foundObj = options.find((option) => option.ID === ID && Object.keys(option).includes(desiredAxis));
    return foundObj[desiredAxis] || null;
};

console.log(getData(parsedData.RTLSTranspondersOption4, 'b', 'X'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getData(ID, desiredAxis){
  const item = parsedData.find(i => i.ID === ID);
  return item ? item[desiredAxis] : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems I get an error due to parsedData.find. I get the following:
```
const item = parsedData.find(i => i.ID === ID);
                            ^

TypeError: parsedData.find is not a function
    at getData (C:\Users\z0043rkh\Desktop\Rotation 3\node-course\notes-app\app.js:12:29)
    at 

```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_